# Use of undefined constant [variable_name] - assumed [variable_.name] error in Php

Tags: php

**Brief** :

I am working on a very simple php project in which i had made a config.php file which holds the all application/configuration variable required to maintain the website for eg: [database/server/uername/pass etc.]

now when i call a variable from config file it throws an error.

**Generation of Problem.**

Hierarchy of files :

```
 - /..
 - lib     
 :  :
 :  - config.php
 :  - include.php
 :
 - index.php
```

**code of config.php**

```
<?php
define('database','dbTest');
?>
```

**code of include.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
echo database; // comment this line when u make index.php
?>
```

*[if u run include.php using xampp u will probably get the out put as **dbTest** reason is simple as we have included **config.php** we are able to access the database variable]*

Now the problem is when we include **include.php** file in another file.

**code of index.php**

```
<?php
include('lib/include.php');
echo database;
?>
```

*now when i run **index.php** i get the following error.*

**error**

Notice: Use of undefined constant database - assumed 'database' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs..\test\lib\sam.php on line 3
database

can you please guide me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the include in *include.php* to:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
```

That's because relative paths are relative to *index.php* not *include.php*. But `__DIR__` will give you an **absolute** path to the folder where *include.php* is stored.

Comment: That was very quick and Correct thnx hek2mgl, but i want ti ask you a question, the same code what i have given before works perfectly on a xammp server on my xp machine but same code gives me error in new xammp installation on my windows8......

similary i have hosted my website on a linux server online, which perfectly works fine, using ftp i have downloaded all the server files and tried to run on my local host which gave me the notice error

is there any possible explanation for this.. i would really like to know

Comment: You mean the problem with the include only exists on windows 8 box?

Comment: may be not with the windows8 but some version difference with xampp.